# Tkinter : Read and store a text when pressing a button

Tags: python, function, user-interface, tkinter, button

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import *
textin = Tk()
fr1 = Frame(textin,width='90',height='8')
e = Text(fr1,bg='white',font=('Calibre',16),width='84',height='8')
#>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
def click1(t8):
    t7 = t8.split()
    if len(t7) > 0 :
        b1.configure(text='Recalculate')
        t = " " + t8.strip().lower()+" "
    return t
de1 = partial(click1)
print(click1(e.get(1.0,END)))
#>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
b1 = Button(textin,text="Calculate",bg='#E3E6FF',font=("Calibre Bold",16),borderwidth='1'
,relief="flat",justify=CENTER,width=16,fg="#010346",activebackground='#B6D1FF',
activeforeground='#010346',highlightbackground='#DCE8FF',state=NORMAL,command=de1)
```

This piece of code -should- read the text in the text widget and execute a function when the button is pressed, this function takes this text and returns it as a value of some variable. but there are two or more problems -as I can see-.

First: I got this error

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 't' referenced before assignment
```

Second: when I try to fix the problem the function `ckick1` doesn't give any results rather than changing the button text and I can't find a way to make this button store the text.

What should I do to fix these problems?

```
     ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Thanks in advance  :)

note: new learner

---

Comment: it seems that the funciton could return `t` without executing the `if` statement so either define `t` at the beginning of the function as `t = None` or similar or place the `return` under the `if statement`

Comment: First of all `partial(click1)` is the same as just having `click1` on its own. Second of all, if `len(t7)` is `0` then the variable `t` would be undefined. Also why are you returning something from a button callback? It will get scraped and the result isn't going to be displayed anywhere.

Comment: @Matiiss I tried to place it under the if statement but the function works for the first click only

Comment: That function isn't working for the first click, it's running before the button is even created. `print(click1(e.get(1.0, END)))` runs immediately, not on a button click.

Comment: @TheLizzard I will fix the second point. and I tried `partial` because the function `click1` has a variable and I don't know how to make the button execute a function with one or more arguments.

Comment: @GeorgeNabil Instead of making the function accept an argument use `t8 = e.get("1.0", "end")` inside the function

Comment: @TheLizzard Is that allows me to use the variable `t8` outside the function?

Comment: @GeorgeNabil You can make the variable global. Why do you want to use it outside of the function?

Comment: @TheLizzard I don't know what a global var is but I will read more about it, and I need to feed this variable to other functions.

Comment: @GeorgeNabil Why don't the other functions call `e.get("1.0", "end")`?

Comment: I want them to call `e.get("1.0", "end")` only when the button is pressed.@TheLizzard

Comment: Also thanks for this hint **You can make the variable global** @TheLizzard